# New MySQL 5.7 installation: Account "Any@%" with USAGE-only, no-GRANT?

Tags: mysql

I've a MySQL 5.7 brand-new installation (via Oracle official RPM) on CentOS 6.5.

Via phpmyadmin, I see this strange "Any@%" account I didn't create, with only USAGE as GLOBAL PRIVILEGES and Grant: No

[image]

Is this legit? I understand that this "account" cannot really use the DB, but I'm missing the point for it to exist! Was it created by the RPM? does it exists by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is legit, as this is a user that gets created by default. It's a fairly dumb default and you should delete the user.

Comment: What I really would love to know is WHY these are created by default. Do you know that? I didn't find an explanation even in the mysql documentation.

Comment: Because somebody at MySQL AB years and years ago thought it would be a good idea and it has never been changed.

Comment: Seems to be exactly as stupid as something important as SSL being developed by mainly one guy and reviewed by another guy who doesn't review.